# Is there a successful method to destroy Buffer instances and deallocate the memory used in NodeJS Canvas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, buffer, node-canvas

Tried numerous ways to force the GC to cleanup the memory without success.
On top of that:

```
buf.remove(); // does not exist   
delete buf; // does not deallocate the memory 
buf = null; // removing references - no result
```

The problem occurs in this routine:

```
 function loadImage(url, finish){
     var Image = Canvas.Image;
     request.get({url:url, encoding:null}, responseImage);
     function responseImage(err,res,body) {
         if(err){
             return finish();
         }
         var image = new Image();
         image.onerror = function(e) {
             finish();
         };
         image.onload = function(){
             finish(image);
         };
         image.src = new Buffer(body, 'binary');
    }
}

loadImage("http://...", function(image){
    if(image){    
        canvasContext.drawImage(image,0,0,100,100 );
    }                
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "without success" ? Can you tell more about how you test that ?

Comment: I have a small function that loads images from URLs into buffers. After the image object is drawn on a canvas I try to destroy the image object and deallocate the buffer memory.

Comment: How are you tracking the memory heap?

Comment: You may want to check bug reports for NodeJS, specifically related to the Buffer and memory leaks. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I got 2 gig of memory after loop created 150 image objects. even assign null to all of it after render process finish still gave me same result of memory leak. so I dig deep to image.cc and found that the solution is simple. Just re assign source of image to null, image object will clean itself then I got my memory back :) (it might trigger onerror event because image load with nothing)

```
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {

  //do anything you want ...

  //clean it by change src to null
  img.src = null;
};
img.src = data;
```